# TYPO3 7.6 Webanalytics without Google

Tags: typo3-7.6.x, web-analytics

Is there any Plugin or Extension to log webstats in Typo3 7.6 without Googleanalytics?
I tried awstats and piwik but it doesn't work.
So is there an easy way to install this Plugins/extensions?

Kind Regards
Ascawath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normaly these statistics work, but you need a little bit more than just TYPO3.
Piwik uses it's own database. Although these tables might be included in the TYPO3 DB. I don't know if there are extensions which realize this. We have an own piwick server which gets called from different instances. so we just include the piwick JS lib which contacts the server.

For awstats you need access to the server logs, as it cummulates infos from there. There was an extension which could simulate the the apache-logging within TYPO3, but I think this does not work any more.